# Counterexample: Nonvanishing derivative (constant) on $\Bbb R$ implies injectivity?

Tags: calculus, examples-counterexamples

I know the case is false if $S \subset \Bbb R$ by Rolle's Theorem, what is a counter example if $S = \Bbb R$?

<strike>I think the "analog" is false on $\Bbb C$, but that's yet to be proven?</strike>

**Addedeum**: Actually it just occurred to me this is false if we weaken the question to non smooth functions; $f = -1/x^2 \implies f' = 2/x^3 \neq 0$. So I am rewording the original question to "constant derivative".

**Addedeum2**: The case for $\Bbb R$ is fine. Ignore the case for $n > 2$.

> If $f'(x) = const$ and $f$ is **smooth**, then must $f$ be necessarily injective on $dom(f) \subseteq \Bbb R$? We may assume that $dom(f)$ is either an interval (done by Rolle) or all of $\Bbb R$.

Comment: If the function is defined on an interval and everywhere differentiable, then the statement is true by Rolle's Theorem.

Comment: By a counterexample do you want an example $f$ which is injective and has $f'(c)=0$ at some point?

Comment: See edit please.

Comment: If the domain of $f$ is not connected, the derivative can not deliver any results about whole the domain of $f$.

Comment: @MooS, see edit please.

Comment: If $f'$ is constant, $f$ is a linear function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f$ is defined (and differentiable everywhere it is defined) on an interval or $\mathbb R$, then Rolle's theorem precisely states, that a non-vanishing derivative implies injectivity.

You say, that you have done the interval-case. But if you want to check injectivity, say $f(a) \neq f(b)$ for $a < b$, you can just consider $f_{|[a,b]}$ and you are in the interval case.

Answer (score 0):

I'll rephrase MooS' answer in my way, I hope this helps. "Nonvanishing derivative implies injectivity" if and only if "non-injectivity implies vanishing of the derivative at one point (at least)".

(I'm using $(P \implies Q) \iff (\tilde {} Q \implies \tilde{}P)$).

The statement "$f(a) = f(b) \implies \exists\, a < c < b \, \mid f'(c) = 0 $" is precisely Rolle's theorem.